# Optional Dependency for Maven when artifact does no exist

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin

I do not know if it is possible for maven to act in this way :

1. An artifact does not exist or is not accessible
2. Mark this artifact as optional

...I am trying to generate a dependency does not exist and mark it as optional and make a buil with Maven in Eclipse ... but it seems that it does not like ..:

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
        <artifactId>myOptionalArtifact</artifactId>     
        <optional>true</optional>   
    </dependency>
```

..... but Maven crashes.... :

BUILD FAILURE
  Could not find artifact com.x.y:myOptionalArtifact:jar:1.0

I'm starting to guess that the optional tag can NOT be used in this sense ???

Comment: Have you read the [maven documatation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)? How you plan to use something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Perhaps you can use [scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).
It will not provides you the optional mechanism (which doesn't exist in maven) 
but you can use it to control the transitivity of the dependency

Answer (score 4):

Maven treats all dependencies you list in the `<project><dependencies>` section of your POM as *required* for your project to build; therefore, any failure to find one of those dependencies fails the build, and this is expected behavior.

The `<optional>` tag you reference is used for when your project is a dependency of another project, indicating to Maven that the optional dependency should be automatically excluded when resolving the transitive dependencies in your main project.

From https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html:

> Optional dependencies - If project Y depends on project Z, the owner of project  can mark project Z as an optional dependency, using the "optional" element. When  project X depends on project Y, X will depend only on Y and not on Y's optional  dependency Z. The owner of project X may then explicitly add a dependency on Z, at her option. (It may be helpful to think of optional dependencies as "excluded by default.")

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to remove a dependency from the dependency tree, you need to figure out all transitive place where it is used and add exclusions to the respective dependencies.

Optional or provided won't help. The artifact remains on the classpath and therefore, Maven tries to load it.